# how to pass htaccess AND Login using python-requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a web application with user/password authentication. Using Python module `requests`, I'm able get my answer this way:

```
data = requests.get(url, verify=False, auth=(USER, PASSW))
```

This is fine. The issue arises with my development server which serve the same application, but protected by a general `.htaccess`.

I'm able to pass the `.htaccess` gate the same way (i.e. passing auth=(USER, PASSW), but not the next login one.

Any idea how to pass a series of gates like that? I tried without success to pass a series of authentication parameters:

```
data = requests.get(url, verify=False, 
                    auth=[(HTACCESS_USER, HTACCESS_PASSW), (USER, PASSW)])
```

---

[edit] As proposed by @furas, I unsuccessfully tried to chain two `requests.get()` :

```
data = requests.get(url, verify=False, auth=(HTACCESS_USER, HTACCESS_PASSW))
print(data.text)  # passed .htaccess, perfect! now on login page
data = requests.get(url, verify=False, auth=(USER, PASSW))
print(data.text) # .htaccess now complains
```

---

[edit2] Trying to keep session alive between requests fails as well as shown in the following scenario:

```
import requests


def debug_get(session, url, auth=None):
    response = session.get(url, verify=False, auth=auth)
    print('== [session.get debug] ==================')
    print('cookies:')
    print('--------')
    print(session.cookies.get_dict())
    print('\nrequests headers:')
    print('-----------------')
    print(response.request.headers)
    print('\nresponse headers:')
    print('-----------------')
    print(response.headers)
    print('=========================================')
    print(response.text[:50] + '[...]')
    return response

session = requests.Session()

# first check page without auth
response = debug_get(session, url_login)  # failed as expected with .htaccess
# provide credentials to pass .htacess is OK
response = debug_get(session, url_login, auth=(HTACCESS_USER, HTACCESS_PASSW))
# retry again to authenticate to the regular web app fails...
response = debug_get(session, url_login, auth=(USER, PASSW))
```

**output**

```
== [session.get debug] ==================
cookies:
--------
{}

requests headers:
-----------------
{'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.18.4'}

response headers:
-----------------
{'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="Restricted"', 'Content-Length': '204', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Server': 'nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)', 'Date': 'Sun, 26 Nov 2017 15:27:03 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'}
=========================================
<html>
<head><title>401 Authorization Required</t[...]

== [session.get debug] ==================
cookies:
--------
{'session': 'eyJjc3JmX3Rva2VuIjoiNTFkZTcxY2JiYjY0YzIwZjI5YjdjNzgwZDEyNmRjNmExNjdjYWRlYSJ9.DPxuyA.TAYFik4yJrebLBaL_zrxTo1IvoM'}

requests headers:
-----------------
{'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Authorization': 'Basic Ymxha2UwcjpNMHJ0aW1lcg==', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.18.4'}

response headers:
-----------------
{'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'X-Frame-Options': 'DENY', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Set-Cookie': 'session=eyJjc3JmX3Rva2VuIjoiNTFkZTcxY2JiYjY0YzIwZjI5YjdjNzgwZDEyNmRjNmExNjdjYWRlYSJ9.DPxuyA.TAYFik4yJrebLBaL_zrxTo1IvoM; HttpOnly; Path=/', 'Server': 'nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)', 'Date': 'Sun, 26 Nov 2017 15:27:04 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'}
=========================================

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- base_flask-bootstrap_[...]


== [session.get debug] ==================
cookies:
--------
{'session': 'eyJjc3JmX3Rva2VuIjoiNTFkZTcxY2JiYjY0YzIwZjI5YjdjNzgwZDEyNmRjNmExNjdjYWRlYSJ9.DPxuyA.TAYFik4yJrebLBaL_zrxTo1IvoM'}

requests headers:
-----------------
{'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Authorization': 'Basic bmljb2xhcy5jb3JkaWVyQG51bWVyaWMtZ21iaC5jaDp0ZXN0MDE=', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.18.4', 'Cookie': 'session=eyJjc3JmX3Rva2VuIjoiNTFkZTcxY2JiYjY0YzIwZjI5YjdjNzgwZDEyNmRjNmExNjdjYWRlYSJ9.DPxuyA.TAYFik4yJrebLBaL_zrxTo1IvoM', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

response headers:
-----------------
{'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="Restricted"', 'Content-Length': '204', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Server': 'nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)', 'Date': 'Sun, 26 Nov 2017 15:27:04 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'}
=========================================
<html>
<head><title>401 Authorization Required</t[...]
```

Comment: What rule in htaccess is causing the issue?

Comment: @TZHX the htaccess itself doesn't rise an issue. As i said, i'm able to authenticate the htaccess, but then I'm trapped. It's just that i dont know how to authenticate twice (first for htaccess, then for regular login) within the same `requests.get()` call

Comment: probably `requests` get page which needs first `auth` and automatically redirect to second which need second `auth` but it will not sent your `auth`- you may have to makes two requests manually with different values in `auth`

Comment: @furas: I can't find a way to "chain" those two`get()`. cf. my edit

Comment: first I thought that requests (after first `auth`) can be redirected to new page (but it lost data for second `auth`) so you may have to use `allow_redirection=False` in first request and get destination URL from response, and use this new URL in second request (with second `auth`). But maybe you have to use Session() to keep informatione between requests.

Comment: BTW: it could be easier if you get url to page with error and all auth data. We could test it and see how it works.

Comment: well, I wouldn't be comfortable by providing those data. Anyway, trying persistent session was looking promising, but still fails. What is weired is that session's header looks correctly updated with the cookie provided by `htaccess` auth, as shown in my [edit2]...